# how to use pm> Update-Database command?

Tags: c#, nuget-package, nuget-package-manager-console

i am trying to run the command `Update-Database` in package manager console. the following errors appears.

this is the connection string I tried using
`"ConnectionStrings": { "sqlserver": "nvlohuqx:YXGg4spm1KAvIidbFufyLMt9HeCZMZDD@surus.db.elephantsql.com:5432/nvlohuqx" }`

it showed this error

> “Format Of The Initialization String Does Not Conform To Specification
> Starting At Index X”

and then after I changed the format for the connection string to the following:

`"sqlserver": "Server=surus.db.elephantsql.com;Database=nvlohuqx;User Id=nvlohuqx;Password=YXGg4spm1KAvIidbFufyLMt9HeCZMZDD;"`

I get this new error:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
> Server)"

Comment: Are those real usernames and passwords?

Comment: yes it is just a database for testing doesn't contain any real data

Comment: If you search the error message you will find many who have come before you with the same issue and also some pointers on how to resolve it. Its not always a programming issue, it could be a networking issue.

Comment: I tried searching stack overflow and other websites for hours.I even asked chatgpt but no solution worked. however Thanks for your respond!

Comment: But what *exact* command line are you attempting to use?

Comment: I am trying to use this Update-Database.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend use Ip instead of domain on Server = ""

Comment: Not a good idea. Just one reason among many: if you want an encrypted connection, you need a full server name to validate the certificate subject name.